# How to interpret $DF(X_s)$ for matrix-valued $F$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-derivative

Let $F \colon V \to L(V,W)$, $X_t = (X_t^1, \ldots, X_t^d)$, $V = \mathbb{R}^d, W=\mathbb{R}^m$,
\begin{align*}
    F(X_t) &= (F_{ij}(X_t))_{1\leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq d}.      
\end{align*}
How should I interpret $DF(X_t)$? Is it a collection of matrices
\begin{equation*}
\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_l} F_{ij}(X_t) \right)_{1\leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq d}
\end{equation*}
for each $l=1,\ldots,d$?